# RegEx how to select any character after a "."

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a string look like this `"123456fd.003g"` and I only want everything after the `"."` which is in this case `"003g"`.

```
[^./]+$
```

I use the above regex but doesn't work.

Comment: Only ever one dot in the input, no trailing data etc?

Answer (score 5):

Use capture groups, your regex would be:

```
\\.([^.]*)$
```

Comment: I think you should remove `[^.]` since OP wants to match any character

Comment: @AmitJoki Hmmm... Could you elaborate?

Comment: just see the title carefully ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki If you _understand_ what it does, then you'd perhaps not comment.

Comment: that was a bit rude @devnull :D

Comment: I think in English "any character" means any character including `.`. But if in your English, if it means something else, then fine.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use *regex* for this task, use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (that takes a *regex*):

```
String splitted = myStr.split("\\.");
String myStr = splitted[1];
```

Note that it's recommended to check if the String actually contains "." before you're splitting.

Comment: Will fail with AIOOB if no dot in the input

Comment: @fge That's why I advised to check before splitting.

Comment: Well, just check the split array length... No need to check for a dot

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using regex,

do this:

```
\.(.+)
```

The First group will contain string after `.`

Comment: The group will contain everything after the **first** dot.

Comment: In my opinion it is what is after the last dot. But, who knows, the question is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can do it:

```
private static final Pattern AFTER_DOT = Pattern.compile("[^.]+\\.([^.]+)");

//
final Matcher m = AFTER_DOT.matcher(input);
return m.matches() ? m.group(1) : null;
```

Supposes that there is only ever one dot in the input!